# What is a proper way to securely use legacy visudo sudoers?

Tags: sudo, wildcards

I wanted to run a script as another non-login user like this:

```
/srv/system/check_alerts.sh <NAME>
```

with 1 argument  of only uppercase letters and **Variable Lengh**.
Because Visudo is so outdated and doesn't allow extglob - than I can't allow variable length arguments.

I tried to add this to sudoers:

```
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [a-z][a-z][a-z]
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [a-z][a-z]

alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [upper][upper][upper][upper][upper]
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [upper][upper][upper][upper]
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [upper][upper][upper]
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [upper][upper]
```

Then running for test:

```
sudo -u alerter bash
```

and:

```
bash-4.2$ sudo -u gmail /srv/system/check_alerts.sh TEST

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for alerter:
```

This still annoyingly prompts for password. Why ?

I don't want to use common "*" wildcard for arbitrary arguments. 
This is not an option, because it allows one to sub-shell with things like "&".

So how to do this properly  to allow variable length argument and avoiding incsecure "*" ? Is there at least one working way, which wouldn't bother with password prompt?

Edit:
Temporarily added this:

```
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh *
```

to visudo and it still asks for password and doesn't respect NOPASSWD option.

Debug:
I run:
    visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/alerter

and added this line:

```
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

After that in "alerter" bash shell I run:

```
bash-4.2$ sudo -u gmail /srv/system/check_alerts.sh TEST
gmail is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Output of "sudo -l":

```
User alerter may run the following commands on test-host:
(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mailq
(gmail) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Update:

Not sure if this matters, but both users "alerter" and "gmail" belong to one group "mycompany".

Update-2:

I removed "sudo" from "check_alerts.sh" script as suggested.
And got command working fine when I have:

```
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh *
```

- this works fine without password prompts.

And now have configured in /etc/sudoers.d/alerter:

```
alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh [[\:upper\:]][[\:upper\:]][[\:upper\:]][[\:upper\:]][[\:upper\:]]
```

This works fine. Thanks to everyone involved into investigation!

Comment: no idea if that would work in this context, but you got the `[upper]` wrong. That would be `[[:upper:]]`

Comment: The character class is `[:upper:]`, and within a bracket expression, it would be `[[:upper:]].`.

Comment: Try using `[[\:upper\:]]*` as your command argument. The sudoers man page points out that you have to escape the `:`

Comment: Okay, but I tried temporarily setting visudo to "alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh *" and it still asks for password and doesn't respect NOPASSWD configuration.

Comment: could be your line is never evaluated because an other line takes precedence. try `sudo -l` to see what's allowed

Comment: I updated question to include this information and also result of debug of allowing "ALL" commands.

Comment: As per this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access
This should be correct. but doesn't work.

Comment: "After that in "alerter" bash shell I run: ...
gmail is not in the sudoers file". You sure you ran that as `alerter`? That message is when you run that as `gmail`

Comment: is there a sudo command in the script itself?

Comment: Yes, it was there. Thanks for pointing that out! I removed it. Now I am able to run command: "sudo -u gmail /srv/system/check_alerts.sh TEST" while having "alerter ALL=(gmail) NOPASSWD: /srv/system/check_alerts.sh *" in "/etc/sudoers.d/alerter".
I will now proceed with tightening alerter sudoers config file.

Comment: I updated answer that reflects, that have returned to initial problem. Suggested correct syntax with colon escaping doesn't work either :(

Comment: wait a minute, this looks like a copy-pasta error. I'll check now and return with feedback.

Comment: That's right, it was. It works properly now.